# Adding help information to custom post edit page

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, dashboard

I have two custom post types created (using `Types` plugin) with a bunch of custom fields.

I need to add a help information, instructions for admins that will show at the top of add new/edit CPT page of dashboard.

How can I add a text visible only on those two pages (`add/edit post type 1` and `add/edit post type 2`)?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function options_instructions_example() {
    global $my_admin_page;
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( is_admin() && ($screen->id == 'custom_post_type_name') ) {

        function add_content_after_editor() {
            global $post;
            $id = $post->ID;
            echo '<div class="postbox" style="background:#0074a2;color:#fff;margin-top:20px;"><div class="inside">';
            echo 'Instructions go here.';
            echo '</div></div>';
        }
        add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'add_content_after_editor' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'options_instructions_example' );
```

It will result in something that looks similar to this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rU66.png

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: An instruction box now appears on that page at least close enough to the top that someone will read it first.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add meta boxes with the content, which help the users. This is more useful. The writers can hide this box and set their personal options to hide the hints from you, if is not necessary for the writers. To add the boxes to the different post type use the specific hooks: `add_meta_boxes_xxx`, `xxx` is for the `post type 1` and `post type 2`.

Small hint to identifier hooks use the plugin [Debug Objects](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects), list Hooks and screen info to find the right anchor.

A screenshot say more, how I find the hook.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the help text above the meta boxes in the Edit Screens easily when using a plugin like ACF or Types.

Answer (score 1):

Accomplish it by using `edit_form_top` hook. Code -

```
add_action('edit_form_top', 'wpse128204_edit_form_top');
function wpse128204_edit_form_top( $post )
{
    if( in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'post type 1', 'post type 2' ) ) ){
        // You want to do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not be more specific for each specific meta box and add the specific help text above each one using the plugin settings.